# Recursive function break

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

The code below makes a post-order traversal through a tree. The intention is to break the recursion when the calling method returns false at a certain condition (see `_walkTree()` below).

```
function _walkPostOrder(tree, callback, ctx){ 
    var continueWalk = true; 

    function _walk(tree, callback, ctx, parent){
        for(var idx = 0, length = tree.length; idx < length; idx++){
            console.log(continueWalk); 
            if(continueWalk) {
                var node = tree[idx]; 
                if(node.children && node.children.length > 0 && continueWalk) 
                    _walk.call(this, node.children, callback, ctx, node); 
                continueWalk = callback.call(ctx, node, parent, tree, idx); 
                continue; 
            }; 
            console.log(node); 
            break; 
        }; 
    } 
    _walk(tree, callback, ctx); 
} 

var json = [{ text: "root", children: [
    {id: "id_1", text: "node_1", children:[
        {id: "id_c1", text: "node_c1"}, 
        {id: "id_c2", text: "node_c2", children: [
            {id: "id_c2_c1", text: "node_c2_c1"}, 
            {id: "id_c2_c2", text: "node_c2_c2"}, 
            {id: "id_c2_c3", text: "node_c2_c3"}]},   
        {id: "id_c3", text: "node_c3"}]}, 
    {id: "id_2", text: "node_2"}]}]; 

//Iterate 
(function _walkTree(){
    _walkPostOrder.call(this, json, function(node, parentNode, siblings, idx){ 
        console.log(node.id); 
        if(node.id == "id_c2_c2") return false; 
        return true; 
    }, this); 
})();
```

What I have trouble with is why the `continueWalk` flag returns back to `true` after it's been set to `false` by the callback. The intention is that it should break the loop at that point, and all loops from the recursive functions above.

This fiddle demo should make it clear: https://jsfiddle.net/xuxuq172/2/

Comment: did you use debugger?

Comment: @Slavik thanks, that's how I figured out where is the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `continueWalk` here:

```
if(node.children && node.children.length > 0 && continueWalk) 
    _walk.call(this, node.children, callback, ctx, node); 
continueWalk = callback.call(ctx, node, parent, tree, idx); 
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to check the content of `continueWalk` as a result of the previous call a line before.

Comment: Ouf I see it now. Thanks Nina!